# React state showing only last value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I tried to loop over my object and add its elements to a array. Then tried to render those array elements in JSX but only the last element is rendered.

Here are the code snippets,

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    Easy: true,
    All: true,
    medium: false,
    hard: true,
  });
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    for (let el in Object.keys(filters)) {
      if (filters[el]) {
        //alert(el);
        //var tmp = [...selected];
        //tmp.push(el);
        //setSelected(tmp);
        setSelected([...selected, el]);
      }
    }
  }, []);


       <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          {selected.map((el) => (
            <h1>{el}</h1>
          ))}
        </div>
```

Here only the **hard** is rendered on the screen but the alert gives correct values.

Comment: Why do you need to check if `filters[el]` do exist?

Comment: he checks if it is `true` or not in order to add it to the selected array

Comment: I need to add it to array only if it is true.

Comment: @GerAlt did you chek my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take into consideration the previous state too in your situation because otherwise you will loose info, so the correct way of doing this is not

```
setSelected([...selected, el]);
```

but rather

```
setSelected(prevState => [...prevState, el]);
```

I also changed a little bit the iteration for keys

[working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hello-world-forked-jmvnzq?file=/src/index.js:0-763)

Comment: i tried this but i am now getting empty array, after rendering.

Comment: I had messed up my Object iteration a bit, It worked just fine , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

When iterating over a structure and enqueuing state updates then you need to be aware the state updates are not processed immediately. The loop in the `useEffect` hook uses the same initial `selected` state value `[]` each iteration and fully replaces the previous state. In other words, the last enqueued update is the one that "sticks".

## Solution

Use a functional state update in the loop to correctly access the previous state, not the state value closed over in callback scope.

Example:

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
  Easy: true,
  All: true,
  medium: false,
  hard: true,
});
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  for (let el in Object.keys(filters)) {
    if (filters[el]) {
      setSelected(selected => [...selected, el]);
    }
  }
}, []);
```

Alternatively you could also just the initial `selected` state value directly from the `filters` state in an initialization function and all the state will be available on the initial render cycle.

Example:

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
  Easy: true,
  All: true,
  medium: false,
  hard: true,
});

const [selected, setSelected] = useState(() => {
  return Object.entries(filters)
    .filter(([key, value]) => !!value)
    .map(([key]) => key); // ["Easy", "All", "hard"]
});
```

[image: Edit react-state-showing-only-last-value]

Comment: Wow!, Thank you so much, would use this way from now.